# How to store a binary string into uint8_t array bits?

Tags: c, algorithm, compression, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have binary string( only `0`s or `1`s) `"0101011111011111000001001001110110"`, for Huffman encoding I want to store each char in the string as bit representation in a `uint8_t` array.

If I write the binary string as-is into a file it occupies 35 bytes. If we can store each binary char in the string as bit representation in `uint8_t` array, it can be stored in ~5 bytes.

```
static uint8_t out_buffer[1024];
static uint32_t bit_pos = 0;

void printbuffer()
{
    printf("Just printing bits\n");
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < bit_pos; i++) {
        printf("%c", (out_buffer[i / 8] & 1 << (i % 8)) ? '1' : '0');
    }

}
void append_to_bit_array(char* in, int len, uint8_t* buf)
{
    
    int i;
    printbuffer();
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (in[i])
        {
            buf[bit_pos / 8] |= 1 << (bit_pos % 8);
        }
        bit_pos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just store it as a `uint64_t` and don't make things hard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That will lead to issues with endianness. Maybe not a problem, but that must be decided on case-by-case basis.

Comment: @hyde True, but that's trivial to deal with.  Using standard functions such as `strtoull()` instead of having to write your own serialization and deserialization code makes the code a lot simpler, faster to write, and much, much less likely to have bugs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If amount of bits exceeds 64, it doesn't fit in one uint64 variable anyway, an array is needed. In general, it's easier to deal with array of bytes than array of larger integers.

Comment: The task is storing binary sequences for Huffman encoding. I guess that it will quickly grow beyond the 64 bits.

Comment: Whst is the question here, actually? Just take the bits from the vharactertsteing and set/clear matching bit in the binary data? You should provide some code.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74591040/edit) your question and provide a [mcve] of what you tried. Suggestion: make a function which gets a byte and adds it to a buffer with a counter for how many bits are in the last byte.

Comment: I see 34 bits there, not 35.

Comment: Now that you have added code, you need to provide more information and ask an actual question, in the body of the question, about that code. What exactly is the input to your code? How is it used? What were you expecting? What is happening? Hint: a question ends with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first decide on what order you want to put the bits in the bytes — i.e. put the first bit in the most significant bit of the first byte, or the least? You also need to have a strategy to deal with the extra 0 to 7 bits in the last byte. Those could look like another Huffman code, and give you extraneous symbols when decoding. Either you will need a count of symbols to decode, or you will need an end symbol that you add to your set before Huffman coding, and send that symbol at the end.

Learn the bitwise operators in C noted in your tag, and use those to place each bit, one by one, into the sequence of bytes. Those are at least the shifts `<<` and `>>`, and `&`, and or `|`.

For example, `1 << n` gives you a one bit in position *n*. `a |= 1 << n` would set that bit in *a*, given that *a* is initialized to zero. On the decoding end, you can use `&` to see if a bit is set. E.g. `a & (1 << n)` would be non-zero if bit *n* in *a* is set.

Comment: I want to put first byte into LSB, I have a strategy to deal with the extra bits  in the last byte. Basically when the bit buffer is full, I do flush the buffer to a file.

Comment: You mean first _bit_? Also it sounds like you did not understand even a little what I said you need a strategy for. Anyway, when you have some actual code and run into problems, post a new question here _with your code_.